# Can't read code blocks from the Stack Exchange android app

Tags: support, android-app, code-block

This occurs in the [Stack Exchange android app](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/?cb=1) released recently to the public.

When someone posts a code block in their question or answer, the code block is cut off on the right hand side, and I can't scroll to the right to view the rest of it. How can I view these code blocks?

Comment: No repro on an android; code blocks appear and are even word-wrapped so there's no horizontal cut-off. VTC as unclear because we're missing information like the mobile phone and browser in question.

Comment: I've loaded the stack exchange app on my samsung galaxy S2. I've accessed stack over through the app. ~ It shows the code block but when I try to slide  to see the rest of the code to the right, it stops.

Comment: Oh, is this the Android app?

Comment: Yes this is the Android app.

Comment: @user2638098 do you have a specific post that you are experience this issue with?  And are you zoomed in at all?

Comment: A screen shot would go a long way.

Comment: On my phone tapping on the code block brings up a window which you can then be scrolled by dragging.

Comment: @psubsee2003 This is a universal thing for the Android app. Code blocks can't be scrolled right - you have to tap on them to open them up for scrolling.

Comment: What I've experienced is that the code block scrolls a few pixels then the scroll gesture gets handled by the viewpager that switches between question and the answers tab.

Answer (score 6):

It's not made obvious* but you need to tap code blocks to view them in full. That will open them up for viewing and they'll be scrollable.

* It really needs to be since you're not the first to be confused about this, and there's nothing suggesting you can do this. This is actually bad user experience design at the moment.